# JetBrains rider does not execute nuget packages with .targets files

Tags: msbuild, nuget, rider

We are testdriving JetBrains as IDE on top of standard dotnet sdk from Microsoft. No Visual Studio installed.

We have a nuget package, that implements an additional build step. It works in VS Express, and on the msbuild commandline, when VS Express is installed, but not in Rider without any VS installed.

What are we missing?

This is the nuget package:

```
\Package.nuspec
\build\nugetPostbuild.targets
\script\createPackageAndUpload.cmd
```

The targets file is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="postbuildPackNuGetTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="Message from MyNuGetCustomTarget. Configuration: $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\nuget_postbuild_script\createPackageAndUpload.cmd $(ProjectDir) $(ProjectFileName) $(ConfigurationName) $(TargetDir)" />
        <Exec Command="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\nuget_postbuild_script\createPackageAndUpload.cmd $(ProjectDir) $(ProjectFileName) $(ConfigurationName) $(TargetDir)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The spec is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>nugetPostbuild</id>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <authors>thewindowsuser</authors>
    <owners>thewindowsuser</owners>
    <projectUrl>http://...</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>bla ...</description>
    <releaseNotes>http://...</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright ...</copyright>
    <tags>some tags here</tags>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="script\**" target="nuget_postbuild_script" />
        <file src="build\**" target="build" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this stuff hasn't been implemented yet. You can track status in our issue tracker: [RIDER-2149](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2149)

Comment: I don't have access to that issue, is it planned for 1.0?

Comment: I've changed visibility of the issue. Yes, it's definitely planned =)